# Check list of strings for substring, case-insensitive

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I want to add a string to a list of strings only if the existing list of strings doesn't already contain the string (even as a substring). Case insensitive.

I have it working as a function, but it's not as Pythonic as I think it ought to be - I have the feeling that this could be a one-liner using a list comprehension, but I haven't figured out how.

Here's what I did that works:

```
def append_if_new(string, strings):

    for s in strings:
        if string.lower() in s.lower():
            return(strings)

    strings.append(string)

    return strings
```

How can this be done without a function, more Pythonically?

Comment: don't try to obfuscate your code. There isn't such thing as "Pythonic". Keep it as readable as possible, and as simple as possible.

Comment: @t.stv I agree with that goal, but I think the answer I accepted is quite readable and simple. Python is good that way - when you use it well, the result is clear and simple code.

Comment: The answer is ok, and there is nothing wrong in coding like that. I am commenting on the intention behind the question. You concerns when wring code should start with computational complexity and end with readability. Somewhere in the middle there is the re-usability. There is coding style, and there are naming conventions but at the end they are purely superficial

Comment: @t.stv I'd say clarity and readability first, computational complexity last. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", said Donald Knuth

Comment: you can say it that way also, my point is that style is not in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if not any(search_str.lower() in s.lower() for s in strings): 
    strings.append(search_str)
```